# Heat diffusion equation (steady state)

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, physics

I am trying to solve this problem:

$\lambda \frac{1}{r} \frac{d}{dr}(r \frac{dT}{dr})+S=0$

[image]

with $S$ being a const source term...

and the boundary contions:

$T(r1) =T1$

$T(r2) =T2$

Numeric values:

```
NumValConst = {
   r1 -> 0.8,
   r2 -> 1,
   S -> 1*10^6*(1 + 1),
   lambda -> 400
   };
```

Inital conditions:

```
NumValCondInit = {
   T1 -> 300,
   T2 -> 350
   };
```

The diffferential equation with intial conditions:

```
   eqDiff = {lambda*1/r*D[r D[T[r], r]] + S == 0};
    inCond = {T[r1] == T1, T[r2] == T2};
    systEq = Join[eqDiff, inCond];
```

Solving and ploting:

```
solX = NDSolve[systEq /. NumValConst /. NumValCondInit , 
  T[r], {r, r1, r2} /. NumValConst]
Plot[Evaluate[T[r] /. solX], {r, r1, r2} /. NumValCost, 
 PlotLegends -> {"T[r]"}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

... but it does not work! :(

BTW: Here is the anayltic solution:
$$T(r)=\int{y(r)}dr+c_{2}=c_{2}+c_{1}\ln(r)-\frac{Sr^{2}}{4\lambda}$$
Now the bc's

$$c_{1}=\frac{1}{\log(r_{1}/r_{2})}\Big(\frac{S(r_{1}^{2}-r_{2}^{2})}{4\lambda}+(T_{1}-T_{2})\Big)$$
$$c_{2}=T_{2}-\frac{\log(r_{2})}{\log(r_{1}/r_{2})}\Big(\frac{S(r_{1}^{2}-r_{2}^{2})}{4\lambda}+(T_{1}-T_{2})\Big)-\frac{Sr_{2}^{2}}{4\lambda}$$

Comment: There're 3 simple mistakes. 1. `D[r D[T[r], r]]` should be `D[r D[T[r], r], r]`. 2. `NumValCost` should be `NumValConst`. (A easy way to avoid this kind of mistake is to always keep an eye on the color of the variable. Notice `NumValConst` is black, while `NumValCost` is blue because it doesn't have a value inside. ) 3. `Plot` has the attribute `HoldAll` so its second argument also needs to be forced to evaluate in your case i.e. it should be `{r, r1, r2} /. NumValConst // Evaluate`.

Comment: @xzczd Nice ! Thanks a lot. Now it works! :)